# Generating an attestation certification for an Ed25519 keypair on the YubiHSM 2

Tags: hsm, yubico, ed25519

Does the YubiHSM 2's attestation mechanism support attesting for Ed25519 keypairs?

The following `yubihsm-shell` session fails:

```
connect
session open 1 password
generate asymmetric 0 100 test-key 1 sign-eddsa ed25519
attest asymmetric 0 100 0
```

with the following message:

```
Failed to attest asymmetric key: Malformed command / invalid data
```

Meanwhile, attestations of both RSA and NIST-B EC keypairs (i.e., ecp256, ecp384) work as expected. The YubiHSM documentation doesn't make any reference to this deficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of YubiHSM2 release 2019.12, the [Known Issues and Limitations](https://developers.yubico.com/YubiHSM2/Releases/Known_issues.html) page states:

```
Attestation currently does not support ed25519 keys.
```